# Magento2 Passing Custom Parameters to Cron Jobs

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, crontab

How to pass custom arguments/parameters for cron jobs in Magento2.

I found an [article](http://www.magento.scommerce-mage.co.uk/cron-job-with-parameters-in-magento.html) related to this for Magento 1.x, I am trying to figure out how to do the same for Magento 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `\Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule` class as a parameter. And, use `\Magento\Cron\Model\Config` to get the config. (Not yet test)

```
/**
  * Cron job config
  *
  * @var \Magento\Cron\Model\Config
  */

protected $config;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cron\Model\Config $config
) {
      $this->config = $config; 
}


public function execute(\Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule $schedule)
{
    $jobsRoot = $this->config->getJobs()
    ....
}
```

If the first way cannot work, we should try to inject `\Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule` on the constructor.

Comment: Khoa - I don't think this answer goes far enough to explain what the user should do, but shows promise that it is is the correct solution - can you please explain as a process what the user should do to configure cron parameters?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "parameters" field in the cron_schedule table by default Magento. Refer [How to pass parameters to Magento 2 crons](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200229/how-to-pass-parameters-to-magento-2-crons/200486)