# How to pass parameters to Magento 2 crons

Tags: magento2, cron

In Magento 1.X we have a field "parameters" in the cron_schedule table. However I don't see it in Magento 2.X

So how can we have parameters for cron jobs in Magento 2? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Spent some time on this and further look into the Schema files and found that there is no "parameters" field in the cron_schedule table by default Magento.

However found that this field was added to the table by a thirdparty extension https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

So my solution for this is either add the field to cron_schedule table or create a new table and join with cron_schedule table as per your requirement. Hope it helps.

Feel free to comment if you have any better suggestions.